# How to implement Custom weighted MSE Loss Function in Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, autoencoder

I wanted to use a custom MSE for an Autoencoder. I have input(X) and output(Y) image of Autoencoder which are actually the same image. now during calculation of MSE we calculate the MSE between true output(Y=X) and Predicted output image (Y').

Lets say, for each image X I have a derived image X' which is a weight matrix for that image. Size of X' is same as X or Y. It contains values between 0 to 1. So, during calculation of MSE, I would like to use X(which is also Y and expected reconstructed output),X' and the predicted outPut Y'.

I will be really thankful, if somebody can suggest me an idea how it can be implemneted in Keras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a loss layer like this

```
class LossLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self,  **kwargs):
        super(LossLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        super(LossLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this somewhere!

    def call(self, x):
        input_image, weighted_image, predicted = x
        loss = weightedmse(input_image, weighted_image, predicted)
        return loss

def dummy_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(y_pred))
```

Use it like this when build the model.

```
input_image = Input(...)
weighted_image = Input(...)
x = Conv2D(...)(input_image)
.
.
loss_layer = LossLayer()([input_image, weighted_image, x])  # x here is the last Conv layer
```

Your data generator must return something like this in `__getitem___`

```
[input_img, weighted], np.zeros((batch_size, 1))
```

## Edit

After difining the tensors above create 2 models like this

```
train_model = Model([input_image, weighted_image], loss_layer)
pridict_model = Model([input_image, weighted_image], x)
train_model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss=dummy_loss)
```

Comment: Thanks Natthaphon. If last layer is returning the loss. How can I get the reconstructed image when I call Model.Predict() ? And how will the model optimize with the dummy loss ? Please excuse me if my questions are too naive. I am quite a beginer into this field.

Comment: Added the code for build 2 models, I edited the previous code above also

Comment: Thanks. AFter calling the below line, the training is working fine.
################ 
train_model.fit([X_train, input_weight],X_train,epochs=10)
############
But if i declare two separate models, does it mean they share their weights after training is done ? Is they have two different set of weight matrix, then the custom MSE doesn't bring any benefit for the prediction. Am I correct ?

Comment: intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=train_model.input, 
                                 outputs=train_model.get_layer("layer_x").output)
################
decoded_imgs = intermediate_layer_model.predict([X_train, input_weight],verbose=1)##############################

This is how i used the predict. But you really helped me a lot. Thanks a lot.